# Should HTML 5 semantic markup be used for styling at all?

Tags: html, semantics, markup

I must admit the HTML5 semantic markup confuses me. I'm talking about these tags in particular:

```
<header>
<nav>
<section>
<article>
<aside>
<footer>
```

Using semantic elements provides the UA with information it couldn't normally get from a `<div>`, but should they be used *along with* `<div>` tags or can/should you style the semantic markup directly?

In other words, what is the proper approach?

This:

```
<div id="content">
    <section>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum></h1>
        <p>Text</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<section id="content">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum></h1>
    <p>Text</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Style the tags themselves. Keep in mind that some browsers have issues with HTML5 tags, so you'll want a script and reset styles to inject the new elements, ala http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the semantic markup tags, you should not also use division tags for the same thing. The semantic tags are a replacement for some of the div tags.

The div tags are of course still useful, for when there is no semantic tag that fits.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your first example is semantically correct, assuming you would have more `section` tags in that `div` tag.

The `div` tag would imply a section of the page that is for content, and then the `section` tag something like posts.

Answer (score -1):

Since the new tags are not universally recognized by browsers, even as candidates for styling, using `div` with `class` is safer. You also have the option of using just `div` with `class` like before, and you don’t lose anything now or in the foreseeable future. No software cares about the “semantics” of the new tags.

Comment: outdated as of 2019

Answer (score -1):

The first example is more safer to use.

```
<section>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum></h1>
  <p>Text</p>
</section>
```

**is the content.**

In order to style this content you can wrap it inside a container eg. `div` with a style hook(class) and apply style to it.